# SQL remove certain duplicate values

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a result table like this (after a query has been run):

```
     id     |  time  | region
12x-4nm-334 | 16:00  | Utah
12x-4nm-334 | 17:00  | California
12x-4nm-334 | 19:00  | Missouri
12x-4nm-334 | 22:00  | California
983-n2n-aq2 |  8:00  | New York
983-n2n-aq2 |  9:00  | New York
```

There are a few other columns in this table, but the important thing is that I want to remove the ids that are only registered to one region from the result. So ids like "983-n2n-aq2" which only show up in a single region (regardless of time) should not be in the resulting table.

Hope this question is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, count(DISTINCT region) as RegionCount
FROM table
GROUP BY
    id
HAVING count(DISTINCT region) > 1
```

If your DBMS doesn't support `count(distinct )` then this should do instead:

```
SELECT id, count(DISTINCT region) as RegionCount
FROM (
    SELECT id, region FROM table GROUP BY id, region
) as table
GROUP BY
    id
HAVING count(DISTINCT region) > 1
```

Comment: Your query is fine for a SELECT, but he asked to remove them, and so you need to add a DELETE query to the main table joined to a subselect on your query.

Comment: @DavidP The problem is, I don't want to modify anything in the tables that I'm pulling from. I'll be using the query multiple times with a lot of different parameters - so I'm trying to have SQL remove these results for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you use MySql

```
    DELETE FROM table 
    WHERE id IN (   SELECT x.id
                    FROM (  select *
                            FROM table t
                            GROUP BY id
                            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT region) = 1
                           ) as x
                    )
```

I don't know for Vertica. Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

Try this (borrowing from Mr Geerkens):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table a INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM table
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING count(DISTINCT region) > 1
) b ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Hmm.. it's giving me a syntax error with "having count(disctinct region)" for some reason

Comment: I had an order statement in the query, so when I put "having" above it, the syntax error was gone, but now I'm getting an empty result set.

Comment: edit: if I put in `having count(distinct region) >1` or `having count(id) >1`, the result set is significantly less, but it's eliminating results that I want, and I'm not sure why

Answer (score 0):

First get the ids that have more than one distinct region (as shown in the subquery), and then use that in a `WHERE` clause to filter.

```
SELECT id, time, region
FROM mytable
WHERE id IN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING count(DISTINCT region) > 1
)
```